# How to Get User's myProjects' Tasks with Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I'm new to Laravel and Eloquent.
In my app, I want to retrieve the current user's and other project members' tasks and show them in the view.
Here's the database relation I have made:

`users` (id)

`projects` (id, user_id)

`user_project` (id, user_id, project_id, role)

`tasks` (id, user_id, project_id)

(I have defined the required foreign keys in migrations)

To explain the relation, each project has a user (who has created the project). But in the `user_project` table, users can be assigned to other projects as well and their role is defined there. For example: There are two **users**:
id=1
id=2

And three **projects**:
id=1, user_id=1
id=2, user_id=2
id=3, user_id=1

**user_project** relationship:
id=1, user_id=1, project_id=1, role=admin
id=2, user_id=2, project_id=1, role=employee
id=3, user_id=2, project_id=2, role=admin
id=4, user_id=1, project_id=3, role=admin

And four **tasks**:
id=1, user_id=1, project_id=1
id=2, user_id=2, project_id=1
id=3, user_id=1, project_id=2
id=4, user_id=1, project_id=3

I want the user `id=2` to be able to see tasks of `project_id=1` because he is invited to that project as employee together with the tasks of `project_id=2` because he has created that project. Of course the user shouldn't be able to see the tasks of project_id=3 because he's not a member. So, what's the neatest way to do this?

Here are the models I have defined:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function projects(){
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
    public function tasks(){
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }
    public function joinedProjects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProjectUser::class);
    }
}

class Project extends Model
{
    public function tasks(){
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }
    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}

class ProjectUser extends Model
{
}

class Task extends Model
{
    public function projects(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Here's the way I'm trying to retrieve tasks of my project members (the ideal way I'm looking for to do this is: `$tasks = $user->joinedProjects->tasks` but I don't know how to do it, so here's how I'm currently trying to get this done):

```
class TasksController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth()->user();
        //I guess there are better ways to retrieve projects, but:
        $projects = app('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController')->allProjects($user);
        foreach($projects as $project){
            $tasks[] = Task::where('project_id', $project->id);
        }
        return view('tasks.index', compact(['tasks','user']));
        //gives error: Property [id] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance
        //when I'm trying to get $task->id in a foreach loop.
    }
}
```

And here's the home controller (I need the `allProjects()` function in HomeController for some other class functions):

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    function allProjects($user){
        $projects = $user->projects;
        $otherProjects = \App\ProjectUser::where('user_id',$user->id)->get();
        foreach ($otherProjects as $project){
            $projects[] = \App\Project::find($project->project_id);
        }
        return $projects;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not only to access it with `$user->projects( )->get( )` ?

Comment: When I use that it only gives the projects that the user has created. The other projects that the user is invited to will be missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you should setup the `joinedProjects` as a [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) instead, that way accessing it will feel more straightforward.

```
// in User model
public function joinedProjects()
{
    // i'm assuming you want to always have access to the role property
    return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'user_project')->withPivot('role');
}

// in Project model
public function memberUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_project')->withPivot('role');
}
```

With this relationship you should be able to call `$user->joinedProjects` to get the list of project that the user has joined.

To get the task, of course you can call the `joinedProjects` relationship and loop through the resulting project like the for loop you have set up. Or as an alternative you can make use of the collection class' [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck) method.

```
class TasksController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // here I put load to eager load the project and task
        $user = Auth()->user()->load('joinedProjects.tasks');

        // OPTION 1: you can loop to get the tasks
        $tasks = collect();
        foreach($user->joinedProjects as $project){
            $tasks = $tasks->merge($project->tasks);
        }

        // OPTION 2: or use pluck (must be eager loaded to work)
        $tasks = $user->joinedProjects->pluck('tasks');

        // $tasks should be unique here, but if it is not you can call the unique method of collection
        $tasks = $tasks->unique('id');

        return view('tasks.index', compact(['tasks','user']));
    }
}
```

Your `HomeController` that you shared can also be simplified with the new relationship

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    function allProjects($user){
        // here i'm assuming user automatically joins a project when they create it
        $projects = $user->joinedProjects;

        return $projects;
    }
}
```

Here's some additional reference to the [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-unique) method i use in the code and the [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. It works. That Auth()->user()->load('joinedProjects.tasks') saves a lot of time! I haven't checked that unique method yet, but I'll check it later. Thanks again.